# Не подтягивается картинка в Одноклассники

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день!
Не подтягивается картинка в одноклассники (также в фейсбук подгружается картинка только со второго раза, но это пол беды).
Сайт - https://factum-info.net

Подскажите как решать вопрос с одноклассниками? 
Заголовок - нормально
Описание - нормально
Ссылка - главная страница, что не правильно
Картинка - вообще нету

Вот пример: https://factum-info.net/interesnoe/foto/277-samye-krasochnye-mesta-na-planete 
(Блок Поделиться в конце статьи)

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Попробуйте явно задать путь к изображению через `data-image` (см. https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/ )

Comment: Не совсем понял как это сделать в CMS Joomla!
Не подскажите?

Comment: Прописал в одной статье явно, выглядит вот так:

<div id="social_share">
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" async="async" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="facebook,vkontakte,odnoklassniki,gplus,twitter,moimir,linkedin,lj,pocket" data-image="https://factum-info.net/images/2_Zabluzhdeniya/5_Raznoe/7_2_fallacy-1.jpg" data-counter=""></div>
</div>

Не помогло, картинка не подтягивается.
https://factum-info.net/zabluzhdeniya/raznoe/299-sbornik-udivitelnykh-zabluzhdenij-chast-1

Comment: У меня так выглядит http://joxi.ru/MAj06aBf4GzpKm

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в хедер

```
<meta property="og:image" content="путь к картинке">
```

плагином или в ручную
в сео плагинах или модулях уже должно быть реализовано.